# "." Is not a command or a bat When trying to serve project

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd

So im currently building/working on a project on my win 10 machine, with nodeJS

But im running into a problem when running it. it says the following.

```
C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Gits\deon>npm start

> deon@1.0.0 start C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Gits\deon
> ./scripts/serve

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! deon@1.0.0 start: `./scripts/serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the deon@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Melonendk\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-16T08_00_31_347Z-debug.log
```

I tried to check the system environment on windows as many others have posted on the internet but with no luck :(

How can I fix this problem?

### Package.json

```
{
  "name": "deon",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./scripts/serve",
    "start-prod": "./scripts/serve-bin",
    "build": "./scripts/build",
    "test": "echo \"Not implemented.\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "contributors": [],
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.18.1"
  }
}
```

### My serve file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

SRC=$PWD/src
HTML=$SRC/html
TEMPLATES=$(find "$SRC/templates" -iname '*.html')

web-build $HTML/begin.html \
  $HTML/${1:-development}.html \
    $HTML/head.html \
    $HTML/begin-body.html \
    $HTML/body.html \
    $TEMPLATES \
    $HTML/end.html \
    serve -m -v --static $SRC --port ${2:-8080}
```

Comment: Can you please post your `package.json`?

Comment: @DavidR yes give me 2 min

Comment: @DavidR Done =)

Comment: Do the paths refer to batch/cmd/shell or Node scripts? For the latter, you can try specifying that `node` is their runner – `"start": "node ./scripts/server"`.

Comment: Running `cmd /C "./scripts/server"` is similar to what `npm start` is doing for you, and results in the same error message. Windows doesn't consider the file, on its own, to be an "executable."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"start": ".\scripts\serve" change it to

```
"start": "node ./scripts/serve"
```

Comment: It works but getting into other errors but that s inside the file luckily so.

Comment: `TEMPLATES=$(find "$SRC/templates" -iname '*.html')
            ^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: Updateing the post

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathan Jonathan mentioned in the comment you need to try this

```
"start": "node ./scripts/server,js"
```

or try something like this

```
 "start": "cd scripts && node server.js"
```